# ColabPro+ limiting runtime to 24hrs

Tags: google-colaboratory

I thought ColabPro+ would allow me to run on a GPU for longer than 24hr, but the VM is getting  killed right at 24hrs, while the (Chrome) browser is open, and a python program has been running the whole time using the GPU.  I tried running in background mode and in this case it killed the VM in about an hour.  What am I missing?

Comment: Now is terminating my (jpynb) jobs after 8hr

Comment: Here's the message: Runtime disconnected
Your runtime has been disconnected due to inactivity or reaching its maximum duration.
As a Colab Pro+ subscriber you have access to the longest runtime durations compared to Pro and non-subscribers, but durations are not guaranteed or unlimited.
To connect to a new runtime, click the connect button below.

Comment: The jobs were *not* inactive. My python job prints a line ever 2-3 minutes and that was still ongoing . It was still terminated after 8hr20min.